# Django + nginx + uwsgi + amazon EC2.

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, uwsgi

This question has been asked so many times, and I have tried each and every one of the solution about deploying the stack, alas.
This is out of desperation I am repeating the question here, yet again.

my deployment scenario :

```
/srv    .
├── env
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── python2.7 -> /usr/include/python2.7
│   │   └── site
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── python2.7
│   ├── local
│   │   ├── bin -> /srv/env/bin
│   │   ├── include -> /srv/env/include
│   │   └── lib -> /srv/env/lib
│   └── src
│       ├── authorizesauce
│       ├── couchdb
│       ├── django-haystack
│       └── django-js-utils
├── html
├── http
├── log
├── solr
├── ssl
└── www
    └── SC
        └── webapp
            └── core
                └── individual
```

Where `/srv/env` is the virtual enviornement
`/srv/log` is for the log file storage
, my `uwsgi reload` file lise in `/srv/reload` my Django application lies in `/srv/www/SC/webapp` all my ssl related files are in `/srv/ssl`, `/srv/solr` is for `apache solr` deployment, `/srv/html` and `/srv/http` are not being used.

`/srv/www/SC/webapp` is the folder having `settings.py` `manage.py`

`/srv/www/SC/webapp/core/` is the core application folder with `individual` as `AbstractUser`

`nginx` version is `1.1.19`
`uwsgi` version is `1.9.18.2`
`operating system` is `ubuntu 1.04 LTS 64 bit`
its hosted on Amazon AWS

**uwsgi configuration**

```
[uwsgi]
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir = /srv/www/SC/webapp

# the virtualenv (full path)

virtualenv = /srv/env

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = settings

# Django's wsgi file
module = uwsgi

master = true
#multithreading
enable-threads = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes = 4

# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /tmp/dev.sc.com.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664
# clear environment on exit
vacuum = true

#pythonpath
pythonpath = /srv/www/SC/webapp
pythonpath = /srv/www/SC/webapp/settings.py
pythonpath = /srv/www/SC/webapp/core
pythonpath = /srv/www/SC/webapp/core/individual

#reloadfile
touch-reload = /srv/reload
```

**uwsgi file**

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**nginx config**

```
    upstream django {
    server unix:/tmp/dev.sc.com.sock;
    }
    server {
    listen     80;
    rewrite ^ https://sc.com$request_uri? permanent;
   }    
    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name .sc.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/sc.bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/sc.key;
        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /srv/www/SC/webapp/media;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /srv/www/SC/webapp/site_static;
        }


        location / {
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/dev.sc.com.sock;
            uwsgi_read_timeout 6000;
            uwsgi_send_timeout 6000;
            include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            uwsgi_param Host $http_host;
            }
    }
```

**The Problem**

When run with `python manage.py runserver` the application runs perfectly well.
As soon as the `uwsgi` deployment is switched on  raise

```
ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'individual.Individual' that has not been installed
```

Starts appearing, and that too very randomly, sometimes it just works (like 50% of the time), I am unsure of what might the problem be.

**Problem 2**

The `uwsgi` shows these logs

```
    unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x199c500 pid: 28242 (default app)
```

**Complete log**

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /srv/www/SC/webapp/wsgi.working.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.18.2 (64bit) on [Mon Oct 28 15:57:49 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 28 October 2013 12:58:05
os: Linux-3.2.0-54-virtual #82-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:31:18 UTC 2013
nodename: ip-10-168-14-146
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /srv/www/SC/webapp
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
your processes number limit is 59476
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/dev.sc.com.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:13:52)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /srv/env
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x199c500
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 364000 bytes (355 KB) for 4 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
added /srv/www/SC/webapp/ to pythonpath.
added /srv/www/SC/webapp/settings.py to pythonpath.
added /srv/www/SC/webapp/core/ to pythonpath.
added /srv/www/SC/webapp/core/individual/ to pythonpath.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x199c500 pid: 28242 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 28242)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 28243, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 28244, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 28245, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 28246, cores: 1)
```

Any pointers would be a great help.

I have told everything I could gather up.

Answer (score 0):

start renaming uwsgi.py to something else (and change module option accordingly), as you will soon get nameclash with the embedded 'uwsgi' module.

uwsgi_param does not take http headers but WSGI/CGI vars (Host and Real-Ip are defintely not needed)

Comment: well your uWSGI logs should have changed now (no more 'callable not found'). If not, double checks paths. The django error could point to the inhability to found python modules or circular dependancies. By the way, starting with such complex config is always hard. Check the official uWSGI WSGI quickstart and when your app is correctly working start integrating it with nginx/os

Comment: As I was telling you, the `./manage.py` was working fine, so I went ahead and did the deployment with `fcgi`